# SetState and Shared Preferences returning null

Tags: flutter, dart, null, sharedpreferences, setstate

I am having trouble identifying as to why setState() is returning null on my shared preferences getString method.
I am calling an async function outside of the initState and the constantly printing null when i check the return string of getString on page load.
I have checked that setString is saving the correct string to the key.
Here is my code:

```
       void initState() {
        super.initState();
        retrieve();
   
      }

       retrieve() async {
       final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       setState(() {
        name = prefs.getString("displayName");

        print(name);
       });
     }
```

Here is where I setString(in the register user page):

```
          try {
            UserCredential result =
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailController.text,
              password: _passwordController.text,
            );
            final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
            final name = _usernameController.text;
            // if (user != null) {
            await user?.updateDisplayName(name);
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, homeRoute);

            print(name);
```

Comment: Where did you `setString` for `displayName`?

Comment: @Josteve page edited. I setString when the user registers an account. My hope is to display the users name when they return after being logged out.(Hot reload)

Comment: Where do you save the name in sharepreferences?

Answer (score 1):

You should set ,username via shared preference before accessing it.

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

In register page.(where you want to set name via SharedPreference before accessing it)

```
await prefs.setString('displayName', 'name');
```

After setting it in registeration you can access like above

```
name = prefs.getString("displayName");
```

Answer (score 1):

When `SharedPreferences` return null value it means you have not set value with your `key` yet. So firstly set something like this:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().reload();

await prefs.setString('displayName', 'Mark');
```

then try to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who have spent the time to respond to help. I hope this answer might help some one else down the track.
I found that Shared Preferences was not saving the data - my code was fine after all. I simply just closed the app and restarted the X code build from scratch and it is now working.....